# Manage RabbitMQ auto-delete queues in different threads. Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

I would like to know if this is the correct way to manage auto_delete queues in different threads (is mainly for testing issues where I don't want the RabbitMQ queues stay when connection closes)

```
import pika
from threading import Thread

class ConsumerThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, callback, queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setDaemon(True)

        self.callback = callback
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        # stablish connection
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(CONNECTION['address'], CONNECTION['port'], CONNECTION['vhost'], CONNECTION['credentials']))
        channel = connection.channel()

        # create the auto-delete queue
        channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue, auto_delete=True)

        # start consuming
        channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        channel.basic_consume(self.callback, queue=self.queue)
        channel.start_consuming()

class Factory:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue_init = "init.queue"
        self.queue_start = "start.queue"

        threads = [ConsumerThread(self.init_callback, self.queue_init), ConsumerThread(self.start_callback, self.queue_start)]
        for t in threads:
            t.start()

    def init_callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        # doing something

    def start_callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        # doing something
```

Answer (score 0):

Pika is not thread-safe. You must be sure that `BlockingConnection` method calls happen on the same thread that the connection and channel are running on. Based on your code, I'm not sure that is going to happen since you call callbacks in the `Factory` class, which seems strange. Why not have those methods in `ConsumerThread` instead?

Pika `0.12` and later will include an `add_callback_threadsafe` method that will schedule a method to execute on the ioloop thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the link. Im new working with pika.
Im calling the callback in the Factory because the factory is an abstract class. of which I'm going to have differents instances (2 queues for instance) and they will execute differents things in the callback.
I was looking on internet and the ConsumerThreads was the best solution i found to consume the queues in different threads, and i had the idea of the execute in the factory the callback. I'm not sure if is correct. But the program works how it must.  
I'm more worried if is a good approach to the problem

Comment: As `add_callback_threadsafe` is not blocking, is there a way to wait for the callback's return?

Comment: No, you will have to implement that yourself via whatever thread synchronization you'd like to use.